# Assume that $a=b$. If the function $f(x)$ is monotonously increasing, then (answer 1) $0<a<1$ (answer b).

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, quadratics, cubics

The given function is $f(x)=x^3-3ax^2+3bx-2$.

I am aware that monotonously increasing means to continuously increase, so I tried getting this function's derivative and then setting it to zero, but to my dismay, even when $b=a$, $3x^2-6ax+3b$ isn't factorable.

I took the quadratic equation and got $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$ as its roots.
The answer is $0<a<1$. I know this because I got it from the answer sheet.
All help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to show that the quadratic function representing the derivative  is nonnegative. For $a=b$ you get $3(x-a)^2.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc in order to get $(x-a)^2$ wouldn't I need an $a^2$?
When I take the derivative I get $3x^2 -6ax + 3a$

Comment: Sorry, while reading on my mobile phone I missed that. Nevertheless the expression can be written as $3[(x-a)^2+a-a^2]$ therefore it is nonnegative if $a(1-a)\ge 0$ hence $0\le a\le 1$ as claimed. You do not need strict inequalities.

Comment: thank you! I see!

Answer (score 2):

Slight typo: I assume you mean monotonically increasing.

Note that a strictly increasing function means its derivative is greater than or equal to 0, not equal to zero as you imply. You correctly calculated the derivative, so $3x^2-6ax+2a\ge0$.

So now our problem is to find a such that for any x, $3x^2-6ax+2a\ge0$. To do this, we will first find the x that minimizes $3x^2-6ax+2a$, because if the minimum is greater than or equal to zero, so will all other values. Taking the derivative and setting to zero, $6x-6a=0$, so $x=a$.

Substituting this back into our first inequality, we get $3a^2-6a^2+3a\ge0$, so $-a^2+a\ge0$ or $a(1-a)\ge0$. This gives us critical points of 0 and 1, and interval testing values for each region on the number line (e.g., test -1, 0.5, and 2) gives us the desired result of $0\le a\le1$.

Another way we could have solved this is by using the discriminant. When we got the inequality $3x^2-6ax+2a\ge0$, we could have observed that this means $3x^2-6ax+2a$ has at most 1 zero, so its discriminant $b^2-4ac = (6a)^2-4(3)(2a) \ge 0$. Simplifying, this gives us $a(1-a) \ge 0$ again, and so the same final answer.

Comment: Ohhh!! Thank you! I actually tried to solve it with the discriminant but I didn't realize that a would be part of the constant and left it out like an idiot lol

Comment: I do have one question though, how did you know that x = a was a minimum? How did you know it's not a maximum? As far as I can tell there is no way of knowing if the sign is positive or negative. 
Is it just that you're assuming since the equation is >0 x would also have to be >0?

Comment: One of two ways: either use the second derivative test, which gives 6, showing it is a minimum; or observe that the leading coefficient is positive, which for a parabola means its vertex is a minimum.

Comment: ohhh  x's coefficent is just 1 (bc 1* x = x) so that means we are positive at the second derivative! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a straightforward calculation based on analysis of quadratic function.
$$\displaylines{f'(x)=3x^2-6ax+3b=3(x^2-2ax+b)\\ =3[(x-a)^2+b-a^2]  }$$ The minimal value of $f'(x)$ is attained at $x=a$
$$f'(x)\ge f'(a)=b-a^2$$
Therefore $f'(x)\ge 0$ iff $f'(a)\ge 0,$ i.e. $b-a^2\ge 0.$ In the case $a=b$ we get $a-a^2=a(1-a)\ge 0$ i.e. $0\le a\le 1.$

Comment: I like this because it's actually what I tried to do in the first place. The only thing I want to know is, how can I realize that I can split it into the form $(x-a)^2 + b - a^2$ ? Are you just adding +1 -1 or something?

Comment: The other possibiity would be to calculate the discriminant of $x^2-2ax+b$ although I prefer to divide by $2$, i.e. calculate the discriminant of ${1\over 2}x^2-ax+{b\over 2}.$ This simple trick gives you the discriminant equal $a^2-b.$ When $a^2-b\le 0$ the quadratic function is nonnegative (as the coefficient in front of $x^2$ is positive). But instead of calculating the discriminant you can complete the first two terms $x^2-2ax$ to the square  by adding $a^2$ and subtracting it,, i.e. $(x^2-2ax +a^2)-a^2=(x-a)^2-a^2.$

Comment: So we complete the square, and then how do we know that the $(x-a)^2$ doesn't effect whether or not the equation is above or below 0?

Comment: I have re-edited the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to view this is that in order for the cubic polynomial function $ \ f(x) \ = \ x^3 - 3ax^2 + 3ax - 2 \ $ to be *monotonically* increasing, which means that $ \ x_1 \ \le \ x_2 \ \Rightarrow \ f(x_1) \ \le \ f(x_2) \ \ , \ $ the function *must not decrease* at its point of inflection when the cubic coefficient is positive.  The location of the inflection point for $ \ f(x) \ $ is given by $ \ f''(x_{infl}) \ = \ 6x - 6a \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ x_{infl}  \ = \ a \ \ . \ $  We thus require $ \ f'(a) \ = \ 3a^2 - 6a^2 + 3a \ = \ 3a·(1 - a) \ \ge \ 0 \ \ , \ $ which holds for $ \ 0 \ \le \ a \ \le \ 1 \ \ . \ $  (For $ \ f(x) \ $ to be *strictly* increasing, we then apply strict inequalities:  $ \ f'(a) \   > \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ 0 \ < \ a \ < \ 1 \ \ . \ ) $

We know that the slope at the point of inflection $ \ x \ = \ 0 \  $ of $ \ y \ = \ x^3 \   $ is $ \ y' \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ $  At the endpoints of the interval we've determined, for $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ we have $ \ x^3 \ - \ 2 \ \ , \ $ which is simply a "vertically-downward shift" of $ \ x^3 \ \ ; \ $ for $ \ a \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ $ we have $ \ x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 2 \ = \ (x - 1)^3 - 3 \ \ , \ $ which is $ \ x^3 \ $ translated "to the right" by 1 unit and "downward" by 1 unit.